# TFIDF and Multilingual Text Classification

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp

I have a scenario, there is a store that has video contents of different languages including English. I want to give an item to item recommendation using TFIDF, but I am confused with stop words. How it is going to perform in diversified languages? And what should be the stop_word?

```
tftdf = TfidfVectorizer()
count_matrix = tftdf.fit_transform(df["combined_features"])
cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(count_matrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Text2Text](https://github.com/artitw/text2text) to get the TFIDF vectors. It supports 100s of languages.

No need to worry about stop words or stemming as described in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.14281).

Answer (score 0):

**Stop Words** is a set of common used words that rather add more noise to the text than useful information. Common stop words in English are: `a`, `the`, `in`, `an`, and punctuation can also be a stop word.

Some libraries suck as NLTK already have established sets of stop words for English. [Example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/removing-stop-words-nltk-python/):

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
set(stopwords.words('english'))
```

You can also customize your stop word list based on the context of the NLP application that you are building.

Each language will have a different set of stop words, an English set of stop words would look like this:

`english_stop_words = ["the","a","an","it","by","or",...]`

while a Portuguese stop word list would look like this:

`portuguse_stop_words = ["a", "o","um","uma","pelo", "pela","ou",...]`

a French set of stop words could be:

`french_stop_words = ["le","la", "à","alors","ce",...]`

So for each language you will need a specific set of stop word for that language. Not necessarily a straight up translation from a stop words set from one language to another.

Again, this is all relative to the purpose of your application. Stop words are used in the pre-processing step of your Natural Language Processing pipeline as a noise reduction step.

[Here is a website that has a list of stop words for several languages](https://countwordsfree.com/stopwords/).

Good luck :)

Comment: Just as an aside, you might want to try *not* using stop words. While they might reduce noise in some information retrieval applications, they still have a purpose in language (otherwise we wouldn't use them).

Comment: Thank you @OliverMason for bringing this up explicitly. As I mentioned on the answer, it is a set of words that add noise, but I did not mentioned that the set could be empty!

Comment: Yeah, I know there is a python package that provides a stop word list for different languages but my problem is my content CSV contains items of different languages and i have to use TFIDF, so should i use stop_words in this case?

Comment: Please rephrase your original question, since what you have asked is not consistent with your comment. Thank you :)